# Association, Commutation and Identity Elements on Binary Operations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, binary-operations, associativity

Is the following closed, associative or commutative?

*f(a, b)* = (a+b)/2, where a, b ∈ Z.

I found that it is not closed but I am not sure how to find whether or not it is associative (I was confused about what c would be), commutative or has an identity element.

Also, does the fact that it is not closed mean that none of the other properties matter (associative, commutative and identity element).

Comment: $c$ must be in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: $f(f(a,b),c)$ is $1/2(1/2(a+b)+c)$; you can try with $a=0$ and $b=c=1$.

Comment: I get (ca+cb)/4 for both so it is associative.

Comment: Ok I am lost at this point then what about commutative and identity element

Answer (score 1):

If we define, for $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ :

> $$f(a,b) = \frac {(a+b)}{2}$$

in order to test for *associativity* we have to check if:

> $$f(f(a,b),c)=f(a,f(b,c))$$

We have :

$$f(f(a,b),c)= \frac {1}{2} [\frac {(a+b)}{2} + c] = \frac {1}{4} (a + b + 2c)$$

while :

$$f(a,f(b,c))= \frac {1}{2} [a +\frac {(b+c)}{2}] = \frac {1}{4} (2a + b + c)$$

Let $a=0$ and $b=c=1$.

Then $f(f(0,1),1)=\frac {1}{4}(0+1+2)=\frac {3}{4}$ and $f(0,f(1,1))=\frac {1}{4}(0+1 +1)=\frac {2}{4}$.

Thus :

> > $f(f(a,b),c) \ne f(a,f(b,c))$.

---

It is of course *commutative*, because :

> $$\frac {(a+b)}{2} = \frac {(b+a)}{2}$$

and thus :

> > $f(a,b) = f(b,a)$.

---

An *identity* element must be an $i \in \mathbb Z$ such that :

> $f(a,i) = a$, for all $a \in \mathbb Z$;

this means that we must have :

> > $$\frac {(a+i)}{2}=a$$

i.e. $a+i=2a$, i.e $i=a$, for all $a$, and this is impossible.

Comment: how is the identity element found?